# Very complicated query that returns categories if products are associated with the category

Tags: php, mysql, function, loops

I have the following function that returns ul menu with products categories only if there are associated at least 1 product with the category. Function looks like this:

```
function getProductCategorieshome() {

    $query = 'select id, 
                     category, 
                     title 
              from products_categories 
              where visible="1" and 
                    parent="0" 
              group by category 
              order by category ASC';

    $result = mysql_query($query) or 
                die('Mysql Error:'.mysql_error().'<br /> Query:'.$query);

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($num_rows){
        echo '<ul id="menu" style="list-style:none;">';
        $htm = '';

        for($i=0; $i<$num_rows; $i++) {
            $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

            //sub category
            $query = 'select pc.id, 
                             category, 
                             pc.title, 
                             p.id, 
                             p.new 
                      from products_categories pc,
                           products_to_categories ptc, 
                           products p 
                      where visible="1" and 
                            parent="'.$row[0].'" and 
                            pc.id=ptc.category_id and 
                            p.id=ptc.product_id and 
                            p.new="1" and 
                            ( expire_date>now() or expire_date=0) 
                      group by category 
                      order by category ASC';

            $result1 = mysql_query($query) or 
                         die('Mysql Error:'.mysql_error().'<br /> Query:'.$query);

            $num_rows1 = mysql_num_rows($result1);

            $q = 'select pc.id, 
                         category, 
                         pc.title, 
                         p.id, 
                         p.new 
                  from products_categories pc, 
                       products_to_categories ptc, 
                       products p 
                  where pc.id="'.$row[0].'" and 
                        pc.id=ptc.category_id and 
                        p.id=ptc.product_id and 
                        p.new="1" and 
                        ( expire_date>now() or expire_date=0) 
                  group by category 
                  order by category ASC';

            $r = mysql_query($q) or 
                    die('Mysql Error:'.mysql_error().'<br /> Query:'.$q); 

            $num_rows2 = mysql_num_rows($r);

            if($num_rows1>0) {
                $sub_htm='';
                for($j=0; $j<$num_rows1; $j++){
                    $row1 = mysql_fetch_row($result1);
                    $sub_htm .= '<li style="list-style:none;text-align:left;">
                                 <a href="./shop/index.php?offers='.$row1[0].'" title="'.$row1[2].'">'.$row1[1].'</a></li>';
                }
                if(!empty($sub_htm)) {
                    $htm .= '<li style="list-style:none;text-align:left;">
                            <a href="./shop/index.php?offers='.$row[0].'" title="'.$row[2].'">'.$row[1].'</a><ul>'.$sub_htm.'</ul></li>';
                }
            } else {
                for($s=0; $s<$num_rows2; $s++){
                    $rr = mysql_fetch_row($r);
                    $htm .= '<li style="margin:0px;padding:0px;text-align:left;">
                    <a href = "./shop/index.php?offers='.$rr[0].'" title="'.$rr[2].'">'.$rr[1].'</a></li>';
                }
            }
        }

        echo $htm;
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

This function returns correct categories if they are with 2 levels depth - so we have parent category and 1 level child category, BUT now I need to have unlimited category depth and the function needs to loop maybe one more time or ??? 
Please help me to solve this.. And I know that mysql is deprecated :)

Comment: Are you having an issue with the SQL query or with the PHP loops? Please help us help you by making your code easy to read.

Comment: Looks like an ideal place to use JOIN there.

Comment: JOIN where? at which stage in the function?

Comment: it's really hard to help without more context

Comment: problem is in the php loop that will execute another series of mysqls.. If can be shorten would be better, but now I am stacked .. I tried loop in the part where I take subcategories, but for example I have 20 main categories, each has 20 child categories and each child category now will have about 20 subcategories.. Loop kills the server..

Comment: next time: please format your code. gives me a headache trying to read it

Comment: OK, I will !
Maybe some recursion will solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to select DISTINCT categories from products_categories:

SELECT DISTINCT category FROM products_categories WHERE visible = 1

Then make a db procedure for building tree path from every leaf node up to the root node

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `treePath`(in category_id int)
BEGIN
DECLARE parent int;
DECLARE current int;
SET @parent := NULL;
SET @current := category_id;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tree_path_tmp(id int);
-- TRUNCATE tree_path_tmp;
WHILE @current DO
    INSERT INTO tree_path_tmp SELECT @parent := parent_id FROM categories WHERE id = @current;
            SET @current := @parent;

END WHILE;
    SELECT * FROM tree_path_tmp;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

From now, once you store the proc in the RDBMS you can get the path by calling the procedure with

```
CALL treePath($categoryThatHasVisibleProducts_id);
```

From there... Good luck! :) now can build the array of all non hidden categories.

btw see Nested Set Model.

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: Enterx, this is very interesting method and this will be my first time to deal with it. Isn't it shorter version to generate the menu? In the link example it looks very long..?

Comment: Enterx I will accept your answer as correct even I managed to succeed another way ! Thanks

Comment: thecore7, shorter version? don't know, haven't studied the subject much but anyway, that makes programming an art.